# Proving an equation involving complex numbers and trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

[image: This is the equation. Apologies if it's blurred.]

Here is the equation if you can't see it in the image: $\dfrac{e^{ni\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\dfrac{\sin\frac{n\theta}{2}}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$

So in trying to prove this equation (using the left hand side) I'm reaching a certain point beyond which it seems impossible to go. It seems that the equation is incorrect.

Here is where I get to, and it seems easy enough to achieve. The left hand side comes out to be equal to $e^{\frac{(n-1)i\theta}{2}}\times \dfrac{\sin \frac{n\theta}{2}}{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}}$

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Show your steps so we can help you figure out where you went wrong

Comment: The equation is not correct. It should read $\frac{e^{ni\theta} - 1}{e^{i \theta} - 1} = \frac{\sin \frac{n\theta}{2}}{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}} \exp \left [i\left (\frac{n - 1}{2} \right ) \theta \right ]$ as you indicate in your question.